# update statement MySQL changing `WHERE` condition with `AND` produced wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following table it has more columns but they are not related:

```
CREATE TABLE `vicidial_lists` (
      `list_id` bigint(14) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `list_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
                               );
```

Wrongly by mistake in the below query `WHERE` condition was replaced by `AND` and limit was not used:

```
update vicidial_lists set list_name = replace(list_name, '15.10.2021', '15.11.2021') and list_id IN (73227,73228,73229,73230,73231) ;
```

This query changed all `list_names` of table `vicidial_lists` to mostly `0` and some records in `1`.

```
LIST ID LIST NAME
73227       0  
73228       0
73229       0
73231       1
```

The problem was fixed , I returned the correct names from backup.
I tried to read about this behavior in `MySQL` docs or if it was listed as a bug but, I didn't find anything.
I am trying to understand why this happen.

My question, more to understand why is:

> Has anyone faced the same behavior , is it listed as a bug  ? Any link provided with related information would be greatly appriciated.

`MySQL` version: 5.6.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, but a valid statement in MySQL.

When a `WHERE`-clause is missing, the `UPDATE` is done on all the rows. The value you are setting for the `list_name`-column will be the result of following boolean expression:

```
replace(list_name, '15.10.2021', '15.11.2021') and list_id IN (73227,73228,73229,73230,73231)
```

becomes either:

```
TRUE AND TRUE => 1
```

or

```
TRUE AND FALSE => 0
```

The `replace`-function returns a string (will be evaluated as TRUE) and the `IN`-clause will evaluate TRUE or FALSE. TRUE and FALSE are handled as 1 and 0 in MySQL, so the `list_name` will receive either 0 or 1.